# Boundedness theorem question proof check

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Here is an attempt at a solution:

[image]

Since $f(x)>0$, $f(x)>\delta$ for all x between $1$ and $2$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would've said something along the line $f(x)$ attains its lower bound say at $a \in [1,2]$, $f(a) > 0$ by definition so let $\delta = f(a)/2$.

Comment: this is what I originally wrote, but in my lecture notes it was done by using g(x), but I'm glad I was at least thinking the right thing :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems having no mistakes. I think it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

"By the algebra of continuous functions" doesn't look like a proper justification to me. I'd prefer something like "because it's the composition of two continuous functions".

But anyway, taking the inverse is unnecessary.

---

You theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$, then:

- There are $m,M\in \Bbb R$ so that $\forall x \in [1,2], m \le f(x)\le M$
- There are $x_m,x_M\in [1,2]$ so that $f(x_m)=m$ and $f(x_M)=M$

Now, since $\forall x\in [1,2], f(x) > 0$, we have $m > 0$ by taking $x=x_m$.

So we have that $\forall x \in [1,2], 0 < \frac{m}{2}<m \le f(x)$ so that $\delta := \frac{m}{2}$ works.